# PgfplotsTable: How to merge cell contents of two tables to one table?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, pgfkeys

I have two tables (sorry, inline tables are not working with `pgfplotstable` 2011/12/19 on my system, even with the option format=inline):

1. Data table (data.csv):

   > X,A,B
   >   U,1.1,1.2
   >   V,2.1,2.2
2. References table (references.csv):

   > X,A,B
   >   U,ref1,ref2
   >   V,ref2,ref1

I want to read both tables with PgfplotsTable and create a new table with `{cell content}={cell content of data.csv}\citep{cell content of references.csv}`. I tried to do this with pgfkeys in the preprocessing step, but was not able to get it working this way. Obviously the macro `\ori` does not get expanded in the argument of `\pgfkeyssetvalue`. Therefore I tried to expand only the second argument of `\pgfkeyssetvalue` using `\exp_args:Nnx` from package `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{expl3}
%
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, trim cells=true]{data.csv}\data
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, trim cells=true, header=false]{references.csv}\references
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
        preproc cell content/.append code={%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\col}{\pgfplotstablecol-1}
            \ifthenelse{\col>0}{
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\row}{\pgfplotstablerow+1}
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{\col}\of{\references}
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ori}
                \expandafter\def\expandafter\ori\expandafter{\ori\citep{\pgfplotsretval}}
                \ExplSyntaxOn
                \exp_args:Nnx \pgfkeyssetvalue {/pgfplots/table/@cell content} {\ori}
                \ExplSyntaxOff
            }{}
        },
    ]\data
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{ref1} ref1 
        \bibitem{ref2} ref2 
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

With this code I obtain the following errors (just one example here):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplotstable@result ...ular}{ccc}X&A&B \\U&\ori 
                                                  &\ori \\V&\ori &\ori \\\en...
l.24    ]\data

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

What I'm doing wrong and how is the best way to do such a table operation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Great question. The problem is most likely (from what I can see) that the macro `\ori` does not get expanded upon `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ori}`. You should then also expand that into tokens. Try and create a minimal example (without scrbook and all unnecessary packages. That will make it easier for other users to help you! :) Enjoy your stay here!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to minimize the example and expand \ori in the argument of \pgfkeyssetvalue - see edited question. However, I'm still glueless about what's really going wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in trying to edit the table *in place*. First of all `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ori}` will set the content to the macro `\ori`. The problem occurs due to `preproc cell content` is done within a group and thus makes `\ori` unreachable outside.

This is also true for any other macro usages within that piece of code you have.
Once you get past one level of expansion in `\ori` you will reach `\pgfplotsretval` which is also only defined within your code piece. `\citep` is not a problem as it is defined outside of the group.

What you need to do is fully expand you arguments and thus use `\pgfkeyssetvalue` with an argument of macros defined outside of the process group, i.e. in the typeset group. Thus the solution will be:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
  preproc cell content/.append code={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\col}{\pgfplotstablecol-1}
    \ifthenelse{\col>0}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\row}{\pgfplotstablerow+1}
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{\col}\of{\references}
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ori}
        % Be sure to have \ori contain the fully expanded values, we do not want to expand \citep
        \edef\ori{\ori\noexpand\citep{\pgfplotsretval}}
        % edef the key so that you do not have any reference to \ori.
        % This is just instead of many \expandafter's
        \edef\tmp{%
            \noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\ori}}
        }\tmp
    }{}
  }]\data
```

This will yield (I have used `\cite` instead of your `natbib` equivalent)

[image]

Comment: Great! It works so far and I understand how it works in principle. However, there seems to be another issue with `\pgfplotstableread`. In spite of setting `trim cells=true` I obtain always a space character appended to the cell contents in the last row of the table. This leads to undefined references (see image attached to the answer). Obviously there is also something different in row counting.

Comment: @bonanza please update your question to reflect this. I did not quite understand what you changed in order to get your image? In any case the space should be inserted due to the `\cite` and thus the undefined reference. Maybe I forgot a `%` termination on each line, try that.

Comment: I changed nothing in your code (except replacing `\citep` by `\cite`). Of course there should be a space between the data and the reference in the final output - but not in the cell content after `\pgfplotstableread`. Maybe I should open a new question since this seems to be related to some other issue with PgfplotsTable? I also wonder why inline tables are not working on my system...

Comment: @bonanza try just place a comma in the cvs, which should constrain the field.

Comment: appending an additional comma to each line in the references table file resolved the undefined references. But this does not explain why on your system pgfplotstable start column counting (sorry for confusing rows with columns in my first comment) in the data table at zero and on my system at one (That's why I have to set `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\col}{\pgfplotstablecol-1}`).

Comment: @bonanza I use the development version of the package, however I am not aware of any changes (but I don't use that package that much). If you try out the development version and check for that, you should be able to know if that is the case. On another note I will consider this question as answered, and my answer seams to supply what you needed. If you need to go further I suggest a new question as these comments will never be found for future reference. :)

Comment: I think, at least the column count issue with pgfplotstable is caused by collision(s) with other packages since in some cases it works also on my system as it should work. However, you provided an adequate answer to my question. Thanks a lot for your efforts!